# remove first line if there is a duplicate

Tags: unix, sorting, duplicates, uniq

I know how to remove duplicate lines using `sort` and `uniq` but is there a way to remove the first line that is the duplicate not the second?

For example, if I have a file with the following lines in it:

```
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
bbbbbbb
ccccccc
aaaaaaa
ccccccc
```

the output needs to be:

```
bbbbbbb
aaaaaaa
ccccccc
```

Do I need to run a loop of some sort or can it be done easily with `uniq`?
And, yes, I know sorting backwards will give me the output but that's not what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: I might have to clarify. The code should keep the newest line if it is a duplicate.

Comment: If it's a duplicate (and you are sorting things) what difference does it make which of the duplicates you remove?

Comment: i don't want to sort it. The output needs to be in original order.
`sort $1 | uniq -d `
ends up giving me 
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc

or 

cccccc
bbbbbb
aaaaaa

neither of which are outputs I need

Answer (score 1):

Add a sequential field to the beginning of each line using paste (1,2,3...), then reverse the list based on the field, and then run uniq ignoring that field.  Then sort by that field to insure they have remained in the right order.  Then remove the field using cut or colrm.

Comment: That doesn't do anything.

`1 aaaaaaa
2 bbbbbbb
3 bbbbbbb
4 ccccccc
5 aaaaaaa
6 ccccccc`

becomes 
`1 aaaaaaa
2 bbbbbbb
4 ccccccc`

Comment: Sry, noticed you wanted to keep the newest one.  Fixed.

Comment: +1, e.g. `nl input.txt | sort -r -k2 | uniq -f 1 | sort | cut -f 2-` or something less hacky in `perl`.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Thanks for doing the heavy lifting!  But I find perl tough, so I salute you on that as well.